# How to make the second address field required during checkout?

Tags: checkout, form-validation

I have config set to display 2 lines for address during checkout (Configuration → Customer → Customer Configuration → Name and Address Options):

`Number of lines in a street address`: 2

How can I make the second line a required field? Only the first field seems to be required. I've looked in the `eav_attribute` table & can't seem to find it listed there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you plan to make the second field mandatory for the checkout, you should make it mandatory in the customer add/edit address form for consistency.

For the client side validation you need to edit each template that holds an address for and add `required-entry` class on the second row. 
Here are the templates I found for this:

- customer/form/address.phtml
- customer/address/edit.phtml
- persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
- customer/form/register.phtml
- checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
- checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
- paypal/express/review/address.phtml
- persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

As for server side validation you need to copy the file

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address.php` to the local folder `/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address.php`. You cannot extend this class because the class is never instantiated.
And you need to add something in the `validate` method.

After this section:

```
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getStreet(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the street.');
    }
```

Add the validation for the second row

```
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getStreet(2), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the correct street.');
    }
```

Comment: is it the same in magento2?

Comment: I hnestly do not know.

Comment: Hi, the first part of this answer has been very helpful, however I couldn't find validate method in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address.php My Magento version 1.9.1 any idea where it could be?

Comment: look for it in the parent classes of the address model.

Comment: How to remove validation for last name (customer address)in adminpanel.