# Customer Field attributes

Tags: customer-attribute

In the order entry process we use First name,  last name, Bill To, Ship to, address 1, address 2... etc.
I like to know how many characters each field will allow?
An can I control how many characters can be entered?

Comment: for validation see here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53063/how-to-make-the-second-address-field-required-during-checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First name, last name, Bill To, Ship's address most of fields are varchar at system.So it max length max 255 characters.